# SSH gets slower over time on macOS

Tags: macos, ssh

I've noticed that on macOS (currently 10.13.3 but I think I've seen this on older versions) ssh tends to slow down over time.  Just now it took 17 seconds to connect to a server.  Then I rebooted, and when I issued the same ssh command it connected in less than 2 seconds.  I've noticed that it seems to deteriorate over time, but I'm not sure what the curve looks like.  I think it stays fast for a few days after I reboot before it slows down, then it suddenly got a LOT slower.  Anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Are these server on the same network? Or are they by cloud service providers?

Comment: They're cloud providers, but it's not a network thing.  It was slow, I rebooted, and it was fast.  This has happened multiple times.